# How find the first element of a list greater than zero (or another criterion) when there is a symbol in the list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to find the position of the first element of a list that is either greater than zero (or some other criterion) or a symbol.

Something like

```
 lst={0,0,k,1,4}
```

and as result

```
 position = 3
```

If there was no symbol the following command would do the job

```
 First[Flatten[Position[lst, _?(Abs[#] > 0 &)]]]
```

If I add `|| MatchQ[_Symbol]` the answer will always be zero.

Many thanks

Comment: How about `First[Flatten[Position[lst, _?(NumericQ[#] && Abs[#] > 0 &)]]]` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 Position[lst, Except[0|0., _], {0, Infinity}, 1, Heads -> False][[1,1]]
```

or

```
 Cases[lst, {zeros : (0|0.) ..., Except[0|0.], ___} :> 1 + Length[{zeros}], {0}][[1]]
```

or

```
 Length@First@Split[lst, #1 == 0 &]
```

or

```
 1 + LengthWhile[lst, # == 0 &]
```

all give `3`.

Comment: I just realized that I misunderstood the question.  Oops.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code.  Why are you looking at levels down to `Infinity` in the first line?  Why are you assuming that the only non-negative numbers are `0`?  Maybe I *still* don't understand the question.

Comment: @kguler - Many thanks, however there is a problem if one has 0. instead of 0 for the first two options.  Third works great.  Many thanks.

Comment: @EdMendes,  excellent point.. will fix in a moment.

Comment: @Mr.W, `{0,Inifinity}` is my "instinctive default" _levelspec_ ; it is not necessary in this case, `1` or `{1}` sufficient. Regarding "the only non-negative numbers..", I was going with the condition `_?(Abs[#] > 0 &)` in Ed's code.

Comment: @kguler - Again thank you ever so much.   Would you be so kind to give details on each function, please?  I am sort of newbie and Mathematica codes still baffle me.

Comment: @Ed, I  will add some annotations later today.

Comment: @kuler - Great!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I misread the question.  Assuming I now understand you just want:

```
lst = {0, 0, k, 1, 4}

Position[lst, _?Positive | _Symbol, 1, 1, Heads -> False][[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

---

My misreading was itself an interesting problem.  I thought you wanted the position of the first positive value as if the symbols were not in the list.  For example:

```
lst = {b, 0, k, 0, 1, 4}

Position[
 Cases[lst, _?NumericQ],
 _?Positive, 1, 1
][[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

because `1` is at position three in `{0, 0, 1, 4}`.

Comment: Wizard - Many thanks. It does not seem to work with a list such as {k,2k,a} though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequencePosition` (introduced in 2015 with V 10.1)

```
list = {0, 0, k, 1, 4};

SequencePosition[list, {0, Except[0]}][[1, 2]]
```

gives

```
3
```